# Extract a table row data in html

Tags: javascript, php

Please see the below while loop which displays the data from a table on loading of the page.

```
<?php 
$idcount;
$jobcount;
$flagcount;
while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) 
    {
        if ($row ['Active'] == '1') {
            $flag = 'checked = "checked"';
        } else {
            $flag = '';
        }
        echo ("<tr>
            <td id = jid$idcount>".$row['JobTypeID']."</td>
            <td id = jtype$jobcount>".$row['Jobtype']."</td>
            <td align='center'><input id=active$flagcount type='checkbox' name='activecheck' $flag disabled ></td>
            <td align='center'><a class = 'toedit' href=# onclick = 'edit($idcount)'>Edit</a> | <a href=# onclick = 'dele($idcount)'>Delete</a></td>
            </tr>");
        $flag = '';
        $idcount += 1;
        $jobcount += 1;
        $flagcount += 1;
    }
    ?>
```

My aim is that, when I click on the `Edit` link, I need to fill a form with the corresponding row data.

I am intending to use javascript to carry out the processing after the data from the row has been copied, but I am not clear about how to extract the corresponding row data for every Edit link.

I am very new to PHP, so please guide me.

EDIT: Below is the code of the form that I am using

```
<form name="job" id="ForNew" method="post"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

        <input type="hidden" id="JID" value="">

        Job Type <input type="text" id="JType"name="jobtype" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($JobTypeValue);?>">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $JobTypeErr;?></span><br> 

        Active? Yes <input type="radio" id = "JRadio"name="radio"<?php if (isset($ActiveValue) && $ActiveValue == "yes") echo "checked"; ?>value="yes"> 
        No <input type="radio" id ="JRadio" name="radio"<?php if (isset($ActiveValue) && $ActiveValue == "no") echo "checked"; ?>value="no"> 
        <span class="error"><?php echo $ActiveErr;?></span><br>

        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit!">
    </form>
```

EDIT 2:
I have written the function `edit()` as follows, but the value that gets returned is in the form of `Object object`. But the value that I need is id name of each specific `<td>`, so that I can copy its value into the form textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function edit(Data)
{
    //Get data with reference to ID
    var Num = String(Data);
    alert("Entered Function! " + Num);
    alert("JID n Data"+$('jid'+Num));
    alert("JID value " + Num);
    alert(console.log(Num));
    $('#JID').val($('jid'+Data).html());
    $('#JType').val($('jtype'+Data).html());
    $('#JRadio').val($('active'+Data).html());
}
```

Even if I do not convert `var Num = String(Data);` to String, I am getting the same result of `Object object`.

Comment: Have you tried anything to generate the form?

Comment: Yes. I have added my code of the form now.

Comment: pass `$idcount` in edit() function and get the related row with that id

Comment: @zan I have done what you have suggested. But the value that is returned is in the form of Object object. Could you tell what mistake I have made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved my own question. The problem was that the `edit(Data)` function was passing the correct value, but the `id` value of the element which needed to be taken the data from, `$('#JID').val($('jid'+Data).html());`, was incorrectly referenced.

The statement `$('#JID').val($('jid'+Data).html());` needs to be like `$('#JID').val($('#jid'+Data).html());`. The `#` before the `'jid'` was missing, which represents the "id" part of an element.

Answer (score 0):

use below code in link

```
onclick="edit(this)"
```

In edit function use this code

```
    function edit(e){
var x=$(e).parents(tr);
$(x).childern("#$idcount") //gives first td value
$(x).childern("#$jobcount") //gives secondtd value
$(x).children("td:nth-child(3)").children("#flagcount").val() //gives input value
}
```

this may help you

Comment: I am getting the following error on Firebug `ReferenceError: $ is not defined var Row = $(Data).parents(tr);` I modified the code to `var Row = $(Data).parents(tr); alert($(Row).childern("#$idcount")); //gives first td value` to check if the table value is being retrieved

Comment: Dont use $ in id,~http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html~

Comment: I removed the $ from `var Row = $(Data).parents(tr);` and now it says `tr` is not defined.

Comment: Changed to `("tr")` and I am now getting an error that says `TypeError: Data.parents is not a function`

Comment: The issue is that there is no data that is being sent from `onclick = 'edit(this)'`. How do I pass values stored in each row, that was dynamically created by PHP, as a single object to the function?

Comment: Do onething add class to the element you want to make onclick function. and try as below link [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nshgq6uw/2/)

Comment: If problem is fixed please tick this as correct answer

Comment: public FileResult Duser3230921, I have edited my code. And have also updated the same in the question. I am getting some unexpected output.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! I appreciate your patience a lot!